# Android Notes App with tags, password protected notes, notes weight(importance level)

Tags: android

+PC or website sync
I'm interested just in text notes, other toys aint necessary, like audio, handwritings, photos etc.

Does such app exist?

Comment: Paid acceptable? What price limit? While waiting for recommendations, be welcome to peek into my list of [Notes apps](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_notes). I had a recommendation, but it won't fit fully (missing tags and weighting).

Comment: yeah, they are. Tags is top criteria along with protection. As I understood, there are no such apps in your list, right? tho thank you for your time

Comment: I didn't say that. I just don't know which app might support that. I found the one fitting my needs (Markor), but *this app* doesn't come with tag support (or I didn't see it). I don't need tags in that place, so I didn't check.

Comment: ok, gonna go through all of them

Comment: If you find one that fits, please [answer your own question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) :) Good luck!